# User overloads of std::size?

Tags: c++, std

Is it standards-compliant to add overloads of `size` in the `std` namespace? I have a class which I can't change, but I'd like `std::size` also to work for it; in a generic setting.

Comment: It's not on the list of things you can add/extend https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: Undefined Behavior

Comment: @molbdnilo Not quite true. It is standards-compliant to add template specialisations to std namespace, for certain templates, for custom parameters. It is not standards-comppliant to add any overloads though.

Comment: You can't **add** *anything* to `std`. There are special exceptions for providing hard specializations (`std::hash` being a common example), but they are few and far between.

Comment: The only way you can get `std::size` to work is by having a `size()` member function.

Comment: Define your custom `size` in the same namespace as your class, and use it as follows in generic code: `using std::size; size(...);`.

Comment: You cannot add overloads to `std`. If your class provides a `.size()` member function, you don't need to.  You could also wrap an instance of your unchangeable class in another class, forward all operations to it, and provide a `size()` member -  then use that wrapper everywhere instead of the unchangeable class. The effort to create such a wrapper will be moderate and, since most member functions will call the corresponding member of the contained object, unlikely to introduce too much runtime overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std):

> It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or to any namespace nested within std, with a few exceptions noted below

And further down on the same page (until C++20):

> It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library function template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and the specialization satisfies all requirements for the original template, except where such specializations are prohibited.

But since C++20:

> It is undefined behavior to declare a full specialization of any standard library function template.

However, thanks to [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) you don't need to provide a specialization for `std::size`. This works:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
size_t get_size_example(const T& t) {
    using std::size;
    return size(t);
}

namespace Foo {
    struct bar {};
    size_t size(const bar& b){ return 42;}
}


int main(){
    std::array<int,5> x;
    Foo::bar b;
    std::cout << size(b) << "\n";
    std::cout << size(x) << "\n";
    std::cout << get_size_example(b) << "\n";
    std::cout << get_size_example(x) << "\n";
}
```

And prints:

```
42
5
42
5
```

Comment: @eerorika I think I confused "not recommended" with "not allowed" (or worse). Will try to rephrase the answer to make it less wrong

Comment: I think my comment was wrong. It is only class templates that may be specialised (unless prohibited). Not function templates.

Comment: @eerorika cppreference [says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) *"It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library function template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and the specialization satisfies all requirements for the original template, except where such specializations are prohibited."*

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili And it says "Until C++20". Ah, so if this is the case, then the removal of premission to define standard function specialisations is a change in C++20. No wonder why I remembered this to be possible while I couldn't find the rule allowing it from the (latest) standard.

Comment: @eerorika oh, I missed that part. Does that mean we're no-longer allowed to specialize any standard functions like `hash` in namespace `std` whatsoever? Sounds like that would break some code. I wonder why they changed it.

Comment: And here is the proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0551r3.pdf

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili `std::hash` is a class. It is not affected.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili thanks, I added the quotes from cppref.

Comment: @eerorika You're right. That would've invalidated the whole purpose of `hash`.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know that. Alas I am also not permitted to add a `size` function template to the other namespace (`Foo` in your example).

Comment: @user2023370 I am not suggesting to add a function template to `Foo`. Also now I am little confused. Why are you not permitted to add something to `Foo` (but apparently to `std` if it was possible) ?

Comment: No matter, I will just define a proxy `size` function in another namespace and call it explicitly (e.g. `Bod::size`).

Comment: @user2023370 but thats the opposite of "generic". Still curious: Why you cannot add to `Foo` ?